# Will starting a virtual machine created by virtualbox immediately reserve physical RAM assigned to it?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-memory

When creating a virtual machine and then installing Android or Windows or other OS on top of it, if I assign 4GB to the virtual machine, will starting the virtual machine  immediately reserve 4GB physical memory, or just 4GB virtual memory and bring in pages via page faults?

My 8GB physical RAM on Thinkpad T400 is often used 80% when not running virtualbox, so I worry that running Android will immediately cause heavy RAM thrashing.

Thanks.

Originated from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088222/booting-up-android-installed-in-virtualbox-seem-to-stuck/1088231#comment1790499_1088231

Comment: *The Intel x86 architecture defines four levels of storage protection called rings, which are numbered from 0 (the most privileged) to 3 (the least privileged). VirtualBox runs a single process on the host operating system for each virtual guest. All of the guest user code is run natively in ring 3, just as it would be if it were running in the host. As a result, user code will perform at native speed when running in a guest virtual machine.* Source: [How Oracle VM VirtualBox Works](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1627061) by Bob Netherton, Gary Combs, Simon Hayler, Jeff Savit.

Comment: I am mainly asking about virtual memory vs physical memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only reserve the required address space, it won’t reserve physical memory (or swap space) until it’s needed. You can see this after starting a process by comparing its virtual size and resident size (`VSZ` v. `RSS` in `ps`, or `VIRT` v. `RES` in `top` or `htop`).

Comment: Thanks. If some user said that ANdroid requires 4GB RAM, while I allocate 1GB RAM for its virtual machine, will that cause my starting Android stuck at a blank screen, as mentioned in the askubuntu post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088222/booting-up-android-installed-in-virtualbox-seem-to-stuck

Comment: [The Android-x86 VirtualBox how-to](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto) recommends starting with 2G, I would start with that...

Comment: Thanks. I change the assigned memory size in the settings of the virtual machine to 2GB and then to 4GB, but starting Android still get stuck at the same place in both cases. I suspect that it is not the memory size but something else.